# Where clause returns nothing MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data table with all the names. The table is only with one cloumn "name"(varchar)when I do

`select * from name`

it will return all the rows

By when I do

```
select * from name where name="(a name which is in the database)"
```

nothing will return(I have tried with a lot of names whiches are in the table). When I do

```
select * from name where length(name)>0;
```

it will return all the rows again.

What can be wrong?

I tried `SELECT name, length(name), MD5(name) FROM name`, the length retruns one number larger then the string length. The I tried to put one space in front and then tried with one space after, neither of these ways help.

Comment: so tell the table structure please.

Comment: Any typos? Spaces or other characters?

Comment: @X.L.Ant: nothing like that,
string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote `(“'”)` or double quote `(“"”) `

Comment: Can you give your query with name which you tried?

Comment: Could you give us an example row if you ran this: `SELECT name, length(name), MD5(name) FROM name` ? It would help us ensure your text is in the table exactly as you see it(and there's no spaces or null characters as padding)

Comment: @diEcho You're right, unless ANSI QUOTES are enabled http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you have invisible characters like spaces or newline or carriage return in your strings.

Try this:

```
select * from name where replace(replace(trim(name), '\r', ''), '\n', '') = 'your_name';
```

If this yields a result, you should update your table to remove those characters.

Comment: You're missing an argument to your outer replace: `replace(replace(trim(name), '\r', ''), '\n'     --HERE-- , '' --/HERE--     )`

Comment: Thanks, there was an invisible /n or /r in the string :)